# Motivo opcional para o voto (tanto para voto-a-favor quanto para voto-contra)

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

## Motivo/Problema:

Algo que frequentemente(todos os dias) vem acontecendo comigo, é aparecer um voto-contra em alguma resposta ou pergunta minha, e eu nem sequer imaginar o motivo disto, e na grande maioria dos casos o meu post está bom o suficiente para receber um voto-contra plausível, que seria o caso de voto-contra mal intencionado, que pode provir desde algo "pessoal" até a uma "disputa" entre respostas onde o autor da resposta X vota contra todas as "respostas concorrentes" ou então até um "porque eu quis".

### Motivo adicional:

O autor da pergunta/resposta saberia no que ele está indo bem **(textos sobre +1)** e no que ele deve melhorar **(textos sobre -1)**, pois em uma pergunta há vários quesitos e detalhes a serem vistos.

## Proposta:

Seria uma pequena janela simples que contém um curto texto acerca do seu voto, sendo ele positivo ou negativo, claro, **você não pode forçar a ninguém a comentar**, mas seria gratificante e útil haver uma listinha, mais ou menos como esta:

```
+1 gostei
+1
+1 ótima formatação
+1 exemplo muito bom
+1
+1
+1 simples e direto
+1 conteúdo excelente!
+1
+1 aprendi muito com isso!
+1
+1 funcionou
-1
-1 formatação ruim
-1 horrível
-1
-1 precisa aprender a usar o site melhor
-1 cadê o exemplo?
-1
-1 porque eu quis
-1 
-1 está errado
-1
-1 não está funcionando
-1 não entendi nada
-1
-1 odeio essa formatação estilo "Artigo Ciêntifico"
```

Nota-se que em alguns casos não resolveu nada e continuamos sem saber porque votaram contra, mas em outros, podemos absorver uma crítica construtiva que vai lhe servir para todas as próximas perguntas ou respostas que forem feitas, e assim **atribuindo um conteúdo melhor ao site, pelos próprios usuários do mesmo.** Porque no fundo sabemos a **importância de um esclarecimento de um voto**, por menos que seja positivo e por mais que seja negativo.

## Vale a pena fazer isto?

Acredito que no quesito **performance** não irá haver problemas pois é algo bem simplório e curto, mas com grande importância principalmente mas não somente para o autor de uma pergunta/resposta feita aqui no site.

## Referência

Uma resposta bem votada no SOen: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/243192)

Comment: Eu acho que (1) essa sua lista de exemplos de comentários não ajuda muito, eles precisariam ter mais conteúdo; e (2) será que não basta ter um lembrete após o voto contra, [como este](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2257/sumiu-a-caixa-de-aviso-ao-dar-voto-contra)? Talvez isso pudesse ser mantido para além dos 2k rep.

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto.

Comment: se bastasse @bfavaretto você veria vários comentários em perguntas e repostas justificando o downvote, coisa que não acontece, e só acontece com o pessoal que já não tem mais o aviso(2k+ rep).

Comment: Pra efeito retórico fica legal dizer que o problema acontece "todos os dias", mas [**na prática**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3082/paulo-roberto?tab=reputation) você só recebeu 3 votos negativos agora em novembro; e antes disso só 1 em agosto. . . . Eu quase nunca recebo negativos e das vezes que isso aconteceu tenho quase certeza de que foi consequência de comentários criticando alguma outra pergunta ou resposta; ou seja, aprendi que comentar pode ser perigoso e deve ser feito com cuidado. . . . http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277836/downvote-commenting#comment121684_277836

Comment: eu frequentemente estou sofrendo com isto, em alguns casos eu até deletei a resposta, talvez possam ter retirado o voto negativo. Mas tenho certeza absoluta que foram mais do que 5 nesses ultimos ~10 dias

Comment: Desculpa a sinceridade crua, mas se não é voto serial e você *sofre* com isso, o problema é seu. Em termos de reputação aqui no nosso *game*, o prejuízo é ridículo pra quem já passou do 3k, e em termos de reputação social (fãs, possíveis clientes, departamento de RH), o número de +1 obfusca completamente esses -1 aleatórios. Admiro muito sua insistência em tentar levantar essa bola, mas por tudo que já li e vi até agora, isso me parece uma furada... :) Eu já tenho tropocentos, tropocentos mesmo, votos pelo Stack afora, ter um pop/aviso me enchendo a paciência cada vez que voto, ah, nem...

Comment: Você realmente acha que eu estou aqui defendendo esta ideia por causa de míseros -1 em minha reputação? Não ligo pra isso. O problema é saber que por **algum motivo** estao me negativando e não ter conhecimento do porquê, isso me martela a cabeça o dia todo, as vezes eu reviso inúmeras e inúmeras vezes minhas respostas e perguntas para ver se tem algum detalhezinho mínimo que seja plausível para voto negativo e não consigo achar. Pode ser que eu esteja cego e não esteja vendo, quem sabe outra pessoa poderia me alertar, e este é o **objetivo principal** desta minha idéia.

Comment: É fato, minhas desculpas, em momento nenhum (aqui ou lá no Metão) você indicou que perda de pontos era um problema. O negócio é que você pode estar sendo "vítima" de algum "inimigo" que tem poder de dar -1 à vontade nos seus posts. Não é um uso correto do site mas é possível fazer isso, e atormentar todos os outros que votam nos *posts* e não nas *pessoas* parece exagerado. Já existe um popup pra usuários com menos de xxx pontos avisando pra deixar um comentário pelo voto negativo. . . . Vou tentar ler tudo de novo (Q, A and comments) e escrever uma resposta completa em breve. Salut!

Comment: Não se desculpe :D afinal você deu sua opinião, todos tem a liberdade de fazer isto. É eu sei que posso estar sendo um **"alvo de ataques"** mas acredito que as chances de ser isso são meio pequenas, não? Pelo menos eu nunca ouvi falar de alguém sofrendo disto, só eu uma vez levei um super massive serial downvote que foi uns -500 mas foram todos revertidos. Se bem que depois dessa eu posso pensar que alguém me odeia e está por ai, HAHAHA. Mas eu adoraria ler uma resposta sua! Vá em frente :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Na minha opinião, votar precisa ser **fácil**. O que "alimenta" o sistema de gamificação do Stack Exchange são os votos, de modo que se começar a ficar "difícil" ou "chato" votar, as pessoas não se darão ao trabalho, e esse aspecto do site acabará por perder a eficácia.

Dito isso, ainda que votar continue sendo "um clique na setinha e pronto", não vejo mal nenhum em se ter meios de facilitar o *feedback* dos usuários, de modo que quem quiser dar esse passo extra ganhe meios (e incentivos) de fazer isso de forma facilitada. Pessoalmente, creio que essa sua ideia pode funcionar, desde que com algumas adaptações:

- Não fazer isso numa janela ou *pop-up* - isso seria "punir" o usuário que vota com mais uma chateação. Penso que talvez as opções extra devessem aparecer na forma de ícone, embaixo do voto (i.e. nessa área em branco à esquerda das perguntas/respostas), bastando o usuário clicar para ativar/desativar (tal como o voto, com um pequeno *"grace period"* antes de ficar bloqueado).
- Não gerar comentários, apenas o próprio ícone com uma contagem. Deixe os comentários para quem quiser escrever alguma coisa "não enlatada".
- Anônimo, tal como o voto em si.

Eu nunca usei o Slashdot, mas sempre gostei das suas classificações (*Insighful*, *Informative*, *Funny*, *Flamebait*, *Troll*), antes mesmo de ler uma postagem lá a gente já sabe o que esperar dela. Sinto falta disso em outros sites, essa dicotomia +1/-1 (quando muito... tem horas que eu *realmente* queria que o Facebook tivesse um botão de "Não Curti") é muito pobre, várias vezes eu já quis dar +1 pelo conteúdo e -1 pela gramática (por exemplo) e/ou tinha algo de útil a comentar mas estava sem tempo/disposição. Em particular porque comentários não são anônimos, então muitas vezes uma crítica gera uma réplica, tréplica, etc, e você acaba tendo que dedicar mais tempo do que gostaria a um detalhe bobo. Mais fácil se abster de comentar...

Esclarecendo: não sou a favor de comentários anônimos. Mas *algum feeedback anônimo* (tal como o próprio voto) é desejável, e creio que torná-lo um pouquinho mais qualitativo - ainda que através de uma curta lista de motivos enlatados - não iria fazer mal algum... (se justifica ou não o esforço de implementar, aí já é outra história)

Comment: Genial, não tinha visto por este lado, você está muito certo quando falou que **ficará "chato" votar** se uma janela pop-up aparecer sempre que o fizer, porém a parte ali que você estava falando sobre dar +1 pelo conteúdo e -1 pela gramática seria ramificar o voto? não entendi muito bem, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Não era minha intenção complicar demais, simplesmente gostaria às vezes de dar +1 e fazer uma crítica ao mesmo tempo (i.e. dois feedbacks independentes). No momento, se voto positivo anonimamente e faço um comentário negativo publicamente, passo a impressão errada (não tem como a pessoa se certificar que fui eu que votei positivo apesar da crítica), *principalmente* se outra pessoa votar negativo e o AP achar que fui eu. Parece besteira, mas já aconteceu isso comigo algumas vezes, e é chato, dependendo do meu humor no dia prefiro não dar feedback nenhum do que me expor a isso...

Comment: Concordo plenamente, e como seria a sua sugestão para fazer algo que pudesse englobar essa situação?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Eu nunca vi com meus próprios olhos, mas soube que no Slashdot às vezes aparece um post "+5 Troll"... :P O ponto-chave é simplesmente que o feedback qualitativo seja independente do quantitativo (i.e. vota-se normal, afetando a reputação do usuário, e se dá zero ou mais feedback enlatado, meramente informativo). Não precisa das opções positivas só aparecerem depois que a pessoa vota +1, e as negativas só quando ela vota -1, todas as opções podem estar disponíveis pra qualquer um que vota.

Comment: Seria uma outra classificação além desta +1 e -1 que temos? não envolvendo reputação e apenas agregando informação ao post?

Comment: Gostei da ideia do @mgibsonbr contudo e mesmo assim não sei se seria bem aceite pela comunidade SE e principalmente pelo staff SE.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Exato! Minha principal inspiração é o sistema do Slashdot mesmo, onde as opções de classificação podem ser poucas mas dão um bom indício da "natureza" da postagem. E de fato, lá essa classificação não influencia na visibilidade de postagem (i.e. +3 ou acima fica visível por padrão, abaixo disso fica escondido), aqui ela poderia não influenciar na reputação do usuário e/ou na pontuação da pergunta/resposta.

Comment: Te dou total incentivo para abrir um [tag:novo-recurso] aqui para ver o que o pessoal pensa @mgibsonbr - eu particularmente achei ótima ideia

Answer (score 10):

Acredito que esse recurso vai servir mais pra alimentar o ego da pessoa do que sendo um recurso realmente útil.

1. Existe o campo de comentário em respostas então lá o autor do downvote ou do upvote pode muito bem sugerir uma melhoria ou tecer uma crítica.
2. Sobre pessoas negativarem apenas para te prejudicar isso existe em qualquer lugar (má fé), mas as vezes o downvote foi porque a resposta é muita crua, e tem vezes que alguns usuários até retiram o downvote quando o autor reescreve a resposta (melhoria).
3. Eu encaro o Stack Overflow com um hobby, respondo as perguntas não em busca de pontuação mas porque eu gosto de ajudar as pessoas **e não espero nada em troca** por isso reafirmo que essa ferramenta não é tão útil, pelo menos no contexto atual que é pergunta x resposta e não OFF-TOPIC, imagine todo mundo que der upvote ou downvote ficar comentando *"legal"*, *"parabéns"* (Esses comentários estão ajudando você a melhorar nas próximas respostas ou estão apenas inflando seu ego)?
4. Isso acaba gerando uma "panelinha", pode acontecer de sempre as mesmas pessoas fazerem os mesmos comentários sempre, como em fóruns de warez: *"Valeu pelo upload"*.

Comment: Para tudo na vida há **exceções**, assim como a questão do **ego** que você disse, e acredito que as suas não invalidam os benefícios que **podem ser** usufruídos pela ferramenta em questão.

Answer (score 5):

Dois motivos para ser contra a ideia:

- A maioria das propostas de comentário automático são ruído;
- Isso já foi proposto (e negado) mais de nove mil vezes no meta do Stack Overflow. Desde a criação do Meta geral, isso já foi proposto pelo menos mais uma dúzia de vezes por lá. Note que na própria resposta marcada como a correta no tópico que você indicou diz que a sugestão não será acatada. Ao invés disso colocaram apenas uma *tooltip* que *sugere* que seja dada uma explicação aos votos negativos.

Se você recebeu votos negativos e quer saber o porquê, passe o mouse sobre o botão de voto negativo ;)

Alguns fatos triviais sobre o assunto:

- Quando os votos são dados sempre por uma mesma pessoa, o SO pode detectar isso como perseguição e desfazer a votação negativa. Se você recebe votos negativos com frequência e eles não são desfeitos, o mais provável é que venham de vários usuários diferentes. Tente melhorar suas perguntas e respostas;
- Mesmo que suas perguntas e respostas sejam boas, sempre há alguém que não entende o que você quer dizer e vota negativo. Mas não se preocupe: se o post é realmente bom, os votos positivos sempre vão superar os negativos;
- Especificamente sobre comentários que começam com +1 ou -1, acredito que serão proibidos por aqui em breve - se já não estiverem proibidos. [Já não são permitidos o Stack Overflow em inglês](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments/).

Comment: Me senti muito ofendido com esta sua resposta, principalmente na parte **"Se você recebeu votos negativos e quer saber o porquê, passe o mouse sobre o botão de voto negativo ;)"**, estás querendo dizer o que com isto? para mim não passa de um insulto, é óbvio que estou reclamando de votos negativos sem razão(ou seja nada do que está escrito na legenda do voto negativo está ocorrendo no post) e não de votos negativos plausíveis.

Comment: **"Tente melhorar suas perguntas e respostas"** volto a dizer que não estou falando de votos negativos plausíveis, e sim de mal intencionados ou com motivos desconhecidos, e sobre **"Mesmo que suas perguntas e respostas sejam boas, sempre há alguém que não entende o que você quer dizer e vota negativo."** era exatamente isto que eu quero descobrir com essa proposta. e **"Especificamente sobre comentários que começam com +1 ou -1, acredito que serão proibidos por aqui em breve"** isso seria **completamente** contraditório! e a toolbox que avisa que deverias justificar seu voto negativo!?

Comment: O Renan está respondendo para todo mundo. Ele está querendo mostrar que a ferramenta já mostra um motivo e que nada vai resolver o problema que você apresenta. O motivo é genérico mas é assim que a SE decidiu que é adequado. E ela já se mostrou arredia a mudar isto. Qualquer mudança teria que ocorrer na rede toda. Eu respeito o que a SE demonstra querer para a rede mesmo quando não concordo, o que não é o caso aqui. Não gosto quando ela usa dois pesos e duas medidas, o que tem ficado mais frequente do que deveria. Não teve ofensa alguma aí. Mas pode sinalizar para os moderadores.

Comment: Sua avaliação de um *post* é diferente de outras pessoas. E é óbvio que se for um *post* seu é ainda mais complicado se manter imparcial. A imparcialidade normalmente ocorre mesmo contra vontade da pessoa. É muito difícil sermos 100% imparciais. E achar que estamos sendo soa arrogante. Podemos fazer o melhor esforço para tornar um julgamento imparcial mas o *background* de cada um vai influenciar na decisão. Me passa impressão que você acha que é possível fazer uma avaliação final 100% precisa em julgamentos. Não é. E não vi contradição em nenhum ponto.