# Respostas negativadas mas sem explicação do motivo

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Venho reparando que algumas respostas são simplesmente negativadas no site porém a pessoa que o fez se quer faz uma crítica informando o porquê do voto contra.

A questão é: Isso não abre precedente para que uma pessoa de má índole que também tem uma resposta no tópico criar mais de um perfil afim de pressionar o terceiro que já respondeu a apagar sua resposta? Ao meu ver no mínimo a pessoa que vota contra deveria justificar afim de enriquecer um debate e não apenas afirmar que é contra ou a favor. Até porque alguma medalhas se dão pelo número de votos contra que você dá.

O que acham?

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/652/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isso não abre precedente para que uma pessoa de má índole que também tem uma resposta no tópico criar mais de um perfil afim de pressionar o terceiro que já respondeu a apagar sua resposta?

Para o usuário votar negativo ele precisa de pelo menos 125 pontos de reputação, essa imposição do sistema visa justamente evitar esse tipo de abuso.

Se ainda a pessoa estiver disposta a criar diversas contas e alcançar essa reputação, é bem provável que as contas criadas por essa pessoa pratiquem fraudes no sistema de votação, como por exemplo votando entre si mesmas para alcançar a reputação de forma artificial e mais rapidamente do que da forma correta. Se a pessoa tiver a paciência de conseguir a pontuação sem usar desse artifício, ainda assim ele estará infringindo as normas do site quando usar de uma gangue para atacar outras respostas na tentativa de denegrí-las.

Para ambos os casos, quando descobertas as fraudes, as contas envolvidas são punidas com suspensão e geralmente até a remoção.

> Ao meu ver no mínimo a pessoa que vota contra deveria justificar afim de enriquecer um debate e não apenas afirmar que é contra ou a favor.

Isso seria interessante, mas já foi amplamente discutido aqui no site, como por exemplo nos tópicos abaixo:

[Obrigar quem deu downvote a comentar o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4126/3117)

[Motivo opcional para o voto (tanto para voto-a-favor quanto para voto-contra)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2259/3117)

[Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/3117)

> Até porque alguma medalhas se dão pelo número de votos contra que você dá.

A única medalha que se ganha ao dar voto contra é a medalha [`crítico`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic), mas ela só vale para o primeiro voto contra.

Para evitar que votos contras em respostas sejam distribuídos em massa, o usuário que dá o voto contra tem o custo de um ponto em sua reputação. Portanto, o sistema tende a desestimular esse tipo de comportamento, sendo muito mais fácil ganhar as medalhas [`Dever Cívico`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) e [`Eleitorado`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) dando votos a favor.

Comment: Interessante essa de quando vc negativa perde um ponto de reputação. Já algo pro cara não sair furiosamente negativando todo mundo...